# Задача: Вывести товары, которые НЕ продавались в данном промежутке времени

Tags: postgresql, join

[image: Решение №1 с помощью WHERE EXISTS]

Одним способом задача решена.
Но хочется также решить только с помощью JOIN.

```
SELECT pr.product_id, pr.product_name, o.order_date
FROM products AS pr
JOIN order_details AS od ON pr.product_id = od.product_id 
JOIN orders AS o ON od.order_id = o.order_id 
WHERE o.order_date BETWEEN '1997-02-01' AND '1997-02-15' 
ORDER BY pr.product_id
```

В результате выводит товары, которые ПРОДАВАЛИСЬ, а нужно НЕ продавались.
Помогите плз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
    SELECT product_id, product_name 
    FROM products 
EXCEPT 
    SELECT pr.product_id, pr.product_name
    FROM products AS pr
    JOIN order_details AS od ON pr.product_id = od.product_id 
    JOIN orders AS o ON od.order_id = o.order_id 
    WHERE o.order_date BETWEEN '1997-02-01' AND '1997-02-15'
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
SELECT distinct pr.product_id, pr.product_name
FROM products AS pr
JOIN order_details AS od ON pr.product_id = od.product_id 
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON od.order_id = o.order_id 
 AND o.order_date BETWEEN '1997-02-01' AND '1997-02-15' 
WHERE o.order_id IS NULL
ORDER BY pr.product_id
```

Comment: @Akina я изменил входной запрос, а поля что и зачем углубляться не стал

Comment: Согласен не проблема. Но оно в исходном запросе и я его не стал менять. Автору виднее. Мне оно не зачем

Comment: @Akina Изменил для всеобщего спокойствия и умиротоврения